minimum of $\mathop{\sum }\limits_{{i = 1}}^{3}\mathop{\sum }\limits_{{j = 1}}^{3}{\left( {e}^{{x}_{i}} - {x}_{j}\right) }^{2}$

Find the minimum of $f\left( {{x}_{1}, {x}_{2}, {x}_{3}}\right)  = \mathop{\sum }\limits_{{i = 1}}^{3}\mathop{\sum }\limits_{{j = 1}}^{3}{\left( {e}^{{x}_{i}} - {x}_{j}\right) }^{2}$ where  ${x}_{1}, {x}_{2}, {x}_{3}$ are all reals.

My attempt:
$f=\sum_{i,j}(e^{2x_i}-2x_je^{x_i}+x_j^2)=3\sum_i e^{2x_i}-2\sum_j x_j\sum_i e^{x_i}+3\sum_j x_j^2$
Then $f_{x_k}=6e^{2x_k}-2 \sum_i e^{x_i}-2\sum_j x_j e^{x_k}+6x_k=0, k=1,2,3$
Can we solve it?
Any inequalities should we apply?

@BrianMoehring Thank you , I have removed it. Any ideas?

The problem is very simple since it is the sum of squares.

Let $a_{ij}=e^{x_i}-x_j$. Since the map $a\mapsto a^2$ is convex, we have
$$
\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2 \ge \frac19\left( \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} \right)^2 \ge 9,
$$
where I used
$$
\sum_{i,j} a_{ij} = 3 \sum_i (e^{x_i} -x_i) \ge 9,
$$
which follows from $e^x \ge 1+x$ for all $x$. The inequality is saturated when $x_i = 0$.

Why the downvote?
